# Excel -VBA Userform that adds values to the end of each column

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a table and then filled it with values as seen in the image. Now I want to fill values in that table with a userform that I created. The code assigned to add item button as seen in the image is only for the first two columns.

The first one works well and adds data after the filled ones, but the second doesn't as it adds data far away from the filled ones.

Here's the Image:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Household" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Entertainment" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Food" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("E7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("E7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Gifts/Donations" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("F7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("F7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Children" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Investment Accounts" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Medical" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Other" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Personal" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Pets" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Taxes/Legal" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Transportation" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please paste your macro, as text? We don't generally like having to type out your macro, then work on fixing.  But I'm going to guess it's your use of `CurrentRegion`, which may not be the region you expect it to be?

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry for that. Im new here.
Here's the macro (I haven't finished all of them as you see because I've used copy and paste to duplicate) --- I've used the same for others

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Household" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it: 
Correct for both RowCount variables

```
'RowCount in household
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'probably + 1 is going to leave a blank, check for it
'RowCount in entretainment 
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'probably + 1 is going to leave a blank, check for it
'... and so on for each field in your form with its corresponding Column letter
```

*PS: "I'm in a hurry. Please ASAP." is not a good manner to ask for things. This is not a we work for free site nor 24/7 availability, especially when you only paste an image for what you want to do.*

**EDIT:**
Replace this

```
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Entertainment" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
```

For this:

```
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Entertainment" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row -6 'since offset is starting at D7

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
```

Comment: +1 for the PS.  Also, just a note to OP: You may want to (err, should) qualify the `Cells()` and `Rows.Count` with the worksheet you expect that to run on (either using `With` or just add the sheet name before `.Cells()` and `.Rows.Count`

Comment: +1 Yep, that's a good practice, however, depends a lot on the context, for example, if the user form is only called from a sequence that can only be accessed within the sheet -IE: a command button- I think it saves you a few lines to code and makes the flow more understandable of how was intended to work.

Comment: It does not works in the correct manner. It adds twice the gap between rows

Comment: Did you try to take out the "+1" as commented in the code? If the behavior it's surpassing by one the desired behavior just change to "-1". The explanation "Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row" this checks what's the last row in the column "C" doesn't matter if there are blanks among, so for example, in the image would be 13, if you want to add to the next one shouldn't be add my string to row 14,   hence 13+1, thus Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row +1 ?

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if that works

Comment: I tried both:
removing the +1 and then the new code but still it outputs me at D24, while I want it at D14

Comment: Yes, it was wrong since you start at D7 so would be 13-6 = 7 to write it in 14, check updated answer again and try the corrected code, please

Answer (score 0):

What I want is just to output in designated cells ---> [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIkXx.jpg)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Household" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("C7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Entertainment" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 6 'since offset is starting at D7

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("D7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Food" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("E7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("E7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Gifts/Donations" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("F7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("F7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Children" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Investment Accounts" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Medical" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Other" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Personal" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Pets" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Taxes/Legal" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If

If CategoriesComboBox.Value = "Transportation" Then
RowCount = Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Worksheets("Data Lists").Range("G7")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
End With
End If
End Sub
```